# Do Ostriches bury their heads in the sand

Tags: biology, ethology, zoology

I have always believed that Ostriches when frightened bury their heads in the sand.
Upon closer re-examination of this belief, I came to the following conclusions:

1. Ostriches typically live in arid areas.
2. Arid areas have dry surfaces.
3. Dry surfaces need significant digging in order to create a depth in which an Ostrich can "bury" its head.

Is there any scientific research discussing this behavior and noting whether it indeed does or does not happen?

Comment: I'm not really a skeptic per se, but I just looooove the question titles on this site :-)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[image: Ostrich]<sub>[Source](http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/kids/stories/animalsnature/animal-myths-busted/)</sub>

From [National Geographic](http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/kids/stories/animalsnature/animal-myths-busted/):

> **Ostriches don't bury their heads in
> the sand—they wouldn't be able to
> breathe!**
>
> But they do dig holes in the
> dirt to use as nests for their eggs.
> Several times a day, a bird puts her
> head in the hole and turns the eggs.
> So it really does look like the birds
> are burying their heads in the sand!

From the [San Diego Zoo](http://www.sandiegozoo.org/animalbytes/t-ostrich.html):

> .. **that’s a myth: ostriches do not
> bury their heads in the sand!**
>
> When an
> ostrich senses danger and cannot run
> away, it flops to the ground and
> remains still, with its head and neck
> flat on the ground in front of it.
>
> Because the head and neck are lightly
> colored, they blend in with the color
> of the soil. From a distance, it just
> looks like the ostrich has buried its
> head in the sand, because only the
> body is visible.

From [ABC Science](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2006/11/02/1777947.htm):

> **The ostrich does many things, but
> hiding its head in the sand is not one
> of them**.
>
> Ostriches have three main strategies
> when attacked:
>
> - they can run away,
> - they
>   can kick,
> - or they can try to hide (eg,
>   when nursing the eggs).
>
> **When hiding,
> they will sometimes lay flat on the
> ground, with the long neck and head
> also on the ground.** In the rippling
> heat haze of their native Africa, they
> can look just like a grassy mound.

From [Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1644/do-ostriches-really-bury-their-heads-in-the-sand):

> There are two theories about how this
> rumor got started.
>
> According to [the World Wide Fund for
> Nature](http://wwf.panda.org/about_our_earth/teacher_resources/remarkable_animals/), **the ostrich lowers its head
> toward the ground in reaction to
> danger**, especially when it's sitting
> on a nest (the female keeps the eggs
> warm during the day and the male sits
> on the eggs at night).
>
> **Male ostriches use their bills to dig
> shallow nests in the sand and move
> their eggs around. From a distance,
> this could look like the ostrich's
> head is disappearing in the sand.**
> That's the other theory.

Comment: This is a very well researched answer, and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: To back this up, try to find a video of an ostrich burying its head in the sand on YouTube ;)

Comment: interesting idea...check this out. It has a refutation of the behavior at (3:20) and theory as to why the myth began: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfvmlDFxJZE

Comment: A lot of the images you see on Google Images also look as if they've been "digitally enhanced" or have things like shrubbery or a small mound in the way of the head to make it appear like that.